# Creating a loop counter in a text file: Ptython

Tags: python, loops, text, counter

This is what i have got so far:

```
counter = (0)

loop = 1
while loop ==1:

a = open ("mustangused.txt", "w")
counter = (str(counter)+str(1))
a.write (counter)
loop = 1
```

i want to make it so it will count the times you have been through theis loop and print the text in a .txt document.

The code above sort of works but the problem is that it will just add the number to the previous number like 12345 without replacing the old number :(
i tried w.write but that did not work.

Comment: Actually not, this is infinite loop (not ptoperly indented), that creates counter variable being string consisting from "1" characters. The length of counter variable increases by 1 with every loop.

Answer (score 4):

```
LIMIT = 10  # adjust this to the number of iterations you want.
with open('mustangused.txt', 'w') as f:
    counter = 0
    while counter < LIMIT:
        counter += 1

    f.write(str(counter) + '\n')
```

It's not really clear what you want to do, nor how many times you want to execute the loop. Nonetheless, this gives you a skeleton for opening a file, looping and writing a value to the file before it gets closed. You may want to make some additions/changes to this to suit your needs.

Some notes:

- I used `with` to manage the file, it will automatcially close the file when we are done or an exception occurs.
- There's no need to convert your counter to string each time inside the loop when you add values, just convert it once when you want to write it to the file.
- Instead of repeatedly opening the same file inside the loop, the file is opened only once before the loop (and automatically closed when the "with"-block is exited).
- All things said, in the end, you could just do a `f.write(str(LIMIT) + '\n')` without a loop to accomplish the same output in the file, so the goal of this question is still unclear to me.

Still, I hope this is somewhat/somehow helpful.

Comment: Thanks man. well i have got a selection menu before that where you can choose between 3 options. Then if the user selects option 1, it will run through the loop and print "1" in the text file and go back to the menu. and so on

Comment: I also have no idea what the purpose of this loop is, but you'd most likely want to use a `for` loop here instead of a `while` loop, which are somewhat rare.

Comment: @Julian I would approach this very differently too, but given that I didn't fully understand the intention of the question, I thought it would be best to stay as close as I could to the original code with the assumption that OP had selected the particular structure with a purpose in mind. (As I mentioned in my last point in my answer, for the given code, the loop isn't even necessary, so it's still a bit of a mystery)

Comment: Agreed :). Wasn't finding fault in your answer.